# o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed

Tags: jhipster, primavera

I get this error after creating entity. Here is my log:

```
2021-01-12 11:56:39.828 DEBUG 9424 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.E.domain.User.authorities          : Close successful.
2021-01-12 11:56:39.875 ERROR 9424 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: jdk11.domain.Libro.scritto in jdk11.domain.Scritto.libros
       
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: jdk11.domain.Libro.scritto in jdk11.domain.Scritto.libros
```

How can i solve? I have already checked the entity names.

Comment: It looks like you're using a JDK I'm not familiar with. Can you try it with OpenJDK?

Comment: I have java version "11.0.9" 2020-10-20 LTS

Comment: That's not the same as OpenJDK. What's the output when you run "java --version"? Mine is:

openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.8+10, mixed mode)

Comment: Sorry if I answer only now.
I run java --version and it comes out this: java 11.0.9 2020-10-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.9+7-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.9+7-LTS, mixed mode)